# How to share database with users located in diferent networks and countries

Tags: database, dns, remote-access

i am developing a windows application that uses a database "MSSQL Server" installed in my pc.
the application has two interface : manager and user
the user will be located in different countries which is mean different network.
the network that my PC is connected to has a high level of security and my PC has local IP address.
what is the best and secure way to share the database and let the users located in network X access my database?
for example: should i use online database or azure or share point or DNS?

if any one has an experience in this kind of connection please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case just use localhost and follow this steps:

```
mysql -u user -p
```

or

```
mysql -hlocalhost -u user -p
```

If you cannot login with this, you must find out what usernames (user@host) exist in the MySQL Server localy. Here is what you do:

Step 01) Startup mysql so that no passwords are require no passwords and denies TCP/IP connections

```
service mysql restart --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

Keep in mind that standard SQL for adding users, granting and revoking privs are disabled.

Step 02) Show users and hosts

```
select concat(''',user,'''@''',host,'''') userhost,password from mysql.user;
```

Step 03) Check your password to make sure it works

```
select user,host from mysql.user where password=password('YourMySQLPassword');
```

If your password produces no output for this query, you have a bad password.

If your password produces output for this query, look at the users and hosts. If your host value is '%', your should be able to connect from anywhere. If your host is 'localhost', you should be able to connect locally.

Make user you have 'root'@'localhost' defined.

Once you have done what is needed, just restart mysql normally

```
service mysql restart
```

If you are able to connect successfully on the macbook, run this query:

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

USER() reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL

CURRENT_USER() reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL

Let us know what happens !!!

Login to the remote server and repeat Step 1-3

See if any user allows remote access (i.e, host in mysql.user is '%'). If you do not, then add 'user'@'%' to mysql.user.

Comment: thank you for the solution and your efforts.
i will try this to check if it will work.
what if i want to use microsoft sql server because they have the free edition
does mysql provide free edition?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for that!

Go to MySQL server
Type the following code to grant access for other pc
mysql > grant all privileges on . to 'root'@'%' identified by 'root_password'; mysql> flush privileges;

Replace ‘%’ with the IP you want to grant access for!

This worked for me!

Comment: in this case i need to add the IP address for all user whom will access the database?
i will publish one application that will be installed in all users PC, so i have to set the connection to the database in the code before publishing, i don't thing that i can set my PC IP address and the connection will be establishing?